# Comparing the value of two null objects without NPE

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-8

This is an extremely basic question but why is the following code returning a null pointer exception?

```
String a = null;
String b = null;

System.out.println(a.equals(b));
```

According to the docs here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)

the `.equals()` function is first checking for null before comparing values.  Shouldn't it return true since they are both null?

Comment: Maybe `if (a != null && b != null && a.equals(b))`, although, once you know `a` is not `null`, you'd be save to use `a.equals`, but what to do when it is?

Comment: yeah that would work but im wondering why that's needed in the first place if its already supposed to be doing that check?

Comment: `null` is not an object, it has no methods, so you can call them

Comment: Use `Objects.equals(a, b)`.

Comment: thanks saka, that did the trick!

Comment: Reasons are well explained already .If you want to go easy way use `StringUtils` :http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#equals(java.lang.Strin)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method you linked to takes in two objects and is a static method. You need to call it like `Objects.equals(a, b)`. Instead you are calling `.equals()` on a null object which throws NPE

Comment: this makes perfect sense now, thanks for explaining it.  ill mark as answer in 10 minutes when it lets me

Answer (score 3):

> *Shouldn't it return true since they are both null?*

nop. since ***a*** is a *null-referenced* object, invoking **ANY** instance method on that object will throw a NPE

so what you can do:

if you are still on java 6 do

```
System.out.println(a == null ? b == null : a.equals(b));
```

and  since java 7

```
System.out.println(Objects.equals(a, b));
```

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem let me correct that! thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

I usually write following method,

```
private boolean equalsWithNull(String first, String second){
    return ((first!=null&&second!=null && first.equals(second)) || (first==null && second==null));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Objects::equals` is the best option, but you can use

```
Optional.ofNullable(a).equals(Optional.ofNullable(b))
```

as well. However I don't really see any cases when you will choose `Optional` approach instead of `Objects`

Answer (score -1):

you can check both values instead of reference,

```
        String a = null;
        String b = null;
        System.out.println(a == b ? "true":"false");
```

it returns true.